# Trying to use Regular Expression in RSpec have_selector line

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm brand new to Ruby/Rails/RSpec, and hopefully this is a dumb/simple question.  I'm currently working on writing RSpec tests for our current projet.  What I am am currently doing involves writing a test for displaying a last login time/date on a page.

What I want to do is just test if the date/time is present in the format we want.  I'm using a regular expression to check for the formatting.  I'm creating the regexp, then trying to use the should have_selector line like so (please excuse the ugly regexp)-

```
it "should display last login date and time" do
  date_time_regex = /Last Login: [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9]:[0-9[0-9]]/
  visit root_path
  response.should have_selector("date_time", :content => date_time_regex)
end
```

When I try run the test I get the following error-

```
1) LayoutLinks when signed in should display last login date and time
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("date_time", :content => date_time_regex)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `include?' for #<Regexp:0xef2a40>
 # ./layout_links_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So it looks like I can't pass in a regexp, but I'm not sure what to do next?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date_time_regex = /Last Login: [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9]:[0-9[0-9]]/

response.should have_selector('data_time') do |data_time|
  data_time.should contain(date_time_regex)
end
```

or...

```
response.should have_selector('data_time') do |data_time|
  data_time.should =~ date_time_regex
end
```

Comment: Still not quite sure I follow- do you mean use 'response.should =~ date_time_regex' or something else?

Answer (score 4):

One thing that will help you is that you can do `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.  So you then get

```
/Last Login: \d\d-\d\d-\d\d, \d\d:\d\d/
```

which is a bit more readable.